# Invalid email addresses in email field at log in from autocomplete of first letter of address

Tags: gmail, login

On trying to log in to a Gmail account, the first field requested is the email of the account. I have two valid email accounts and these are offered in the pop up list, but there are other addresses offered which are invalid. How can I get rid of these?

Comment: What browser? What address are you trying to log in from, google.com/mail?

Comment: Delete your Gmail/Google Account cookies from your browser and the suggestions should disappear (your two accounts will disappear as well until you login with both of them again).

Answer (score 1):

If you are at a normal login page with the username and password fields, clear your browser's data cache.

If you are presented with the following screen, click **Manage accounts on this device**, then delete on the next screen. An `x` will appear next to the email addresses and you can delete them that way.
[image]